# Can't install PECL on Xubuntu (unable to locate package)

Tags: apt, php

I tried `sudo apt-get install php-pecl`, but I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package php-pecl
```

Comment: have a look at: [Install PECL packages on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/403327/install-pecl-packages-on-ubuntu), see if that helps you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no `php-pecl` package.  The `pecl` binary is contained in `php-pear` package, e.g. do:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

You can use `apt-file` from `apt-file` package to search for files contained in package not installed locally.  Try:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search /usr/bin/pecl
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `php-pecl` package in the official repositories.

Maybe you mean [`php-pecl-http`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php-pecl-http) from the `universe` repository of 16.04 instead?

Additionally, you might be interested in [Install PECL packages on ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403327/install-pecl-packages-on-ubuntu)?